# Python: geopy.distance.geodesic in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing, geopy

I have the following data and I am trying to compute the geopy distance from one observation to another using their latitudes and longitudes.

```
trip3

>>
    trip_id                                     latitude    longitude
0   9367efd103c7314d70446927130c9b98778fbbd0    57.728867   11.949463
1   8a8449635c10cc4b8e7841e517f27e2652c57ea3    57.728867   11.949463
2   8a8449635c10cc4b8e7841e517f27e2652c57ea3    57.728954   11.949368
3   8a8449635c10cc4b8e7841e517f27e2652c57ea3    57.728867   11.949463
4   8a8449635c10cc4b8e7841e517f27e2652c57ea3    57.728954   11.949368
... ... ... ...
30473   019ebd48fe9c9ab20051e9de1d5ddfc6fd13c55b    57.691685   12.009715
30474   019ebd48fe9c9ab20051e9de1d5ddfc6fd13c55b    57.691452   12.010811
30475   019ebd48fe9c9ab20051e9de1d5ddfc6fd13c55b    57.690945   12.011210
30476   019ebd48fe9c9ab20051e9de1d5ddfc6fd13c55b    57.690468   12.011681
30477   d0fe1a916d47228c09911b487146731d75c7d728    57.690361   12.011670
```

To compute the distance I am trying:

```
# Empty string
current_trip_id = ""

# Creating a new column for the distance between observations of the same trip
# all rows have a default value of 0
trip3["geopy_distance"] = 0

# Loop
for index,row in trip3.iterrows():
    
    if row["trip_id"] == current_trip_id:
    
        lat_coor = row["latitude"]
        lon_coor = row["longitude"]

        final_pos = row["latitude"], row["longitude"]

        my_dist = geopy.distance.geodesic(initial_pos[0], initial_pos[1], final_pos[0], final_pos[1])
        trip3.loc[index, "geopy_distance"] = my_dist

    # Update loop
    current_trip_id = row["trip_id"]
    
    initial_pos = row["latitude"], row["longitude"]
```

However, I get the error:

**A single number has been passed to the Point constructor. This is probably a mistake, because constructing a Point with just a latitude seems senseless. If this is exactly what was meant, then pass the zero longitude explicitly to get rid of this error.**

This code worked with a defined haversine distance function but it's not working with geopy. I am interested in seeing how the two differ. So I'd only want to calculate the geopy distance as supposedly this tends to be more accurate than haversine.

**How can my loop be improved to compute this distance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.distance.geodesic), `geopy.distance.geodesic` takes its arguments as (lat, lon) tuples.

Comment: Changing to '''my_dist = geopy.distance.geodesic((initial_pos[0], initial_pos[1]), (final_pos[0], final_pos[1]))''' solved the problem. Thank you!